# Systems operation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have these equations and I want to use matrices to solve for the variables. How would I have to set up the matrices, if that is possible?

> $$\begin{cases}C_1 = 12 + 0.1 {h_1}^2\\
> C_2 = 2 + {h_2}^2 + 10(h_2 + h_4)\\
> C_3 = 10 + 0.1 {h_3}^2\\
> C_4 = 3 + {h_4}^2 + 10(h_2 + h_4)
> \end{cases} \text{ subject to }
> \begin{cases}C_1 = C_2\\
> C_3 = C_4\\
> h_3 + h_4 = 10\\
> h_1 + h_2 = 10\\
> h_1 + h_2 + h_3 + h_4 = 20
> \end{cases}
> $$

Comment: You have nine equations, but only eight variables. There might well not be any solutions.

Comment: Also, as the equations are not all linear, you won't be able to set this up as a simple matrix equation $Ax=b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you.